# How to add ToolStripSplitButton to Visual Studio Toolbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and I have come across a need to use the ToolStripSplitButton button.  I figured out from the [reference material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that ToolStripSplitButton is a form found under the System.Windows.Forms.

When I attempt to add this to my toolbox to try to use, I am unable to find ToolStripSplitButton, does anybody know how I can add this to my Visual Studio 2010 so I can use it?  I don't care if it's not in the toolbox, I just want to make sure the assembly reference is present so I can actually use it.

[image]

Comment: The ToolStripItem classes, like ToolStripSplitButton, are not controls that are derived from the Control class.  They are light-weight controls that don't have a window of their own.  Which is why you can't find it back in the toolbox.

They need a host window that provides the actual window at runtime.  A ToolStrip.  Once you drop one on your form, you'll have little trouble finding the SplitButton back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolStripSplitButton` can be used only as `ToolStripItem` of a `ToolStrip` (contained in `ToolStrip.Items`). It's designed so that you can't use it as a normal control. It doesn't have a `Parent` property, and I guess it also doesn't have a `Handle` property. The inheritance tree is:

```
ToolStripSplitButton
   -> ToolStripDropDownItem
       -> ToolStripItem
          -> Component
             -> ...
```

Normally, you have to add some `ToolStrip` to host `ToolStripSplitButton`.

If you want to use code, here is a simple example:

```
ToolStrip toolStrip1 = new ToolStrip();
ToolStripSplitButton splitButton1 = new ToolStripSplitButton("Hi there"){Owner = toolStrip1};
//you can add items to ToolStripSplitButton via ToolStripSplitButton.DropDownItems
```

More info [ToolStripSplitButton](http://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.aspx&ei=dyAJUpL5PK-YiAewy4GgAw&usg=AFQjCNHxz5h4zM8IZ3ggX724R6gOm5hUmg&sig2=ulQUheItnA3JS5UDY-16Iw&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aGc)

Answer (score 1):

It's inherited from and dependent on ToolStripDropDown so you can't use it as a stand-alone control.
You can use it as a child control for ToolStripDropDown.